# How to output exactly what is read in from a FORTRAN READ statement?

Tags: arrays, io, fortran

Consider this program,

```
      PROGRAM FOO

      CHARACTER(LEN=25) :: INP
      CHARACTER(LEN=50) :: C

      INP = 'The quick brown fox ...'

      READ (INP, '(A)') C
      WRITE (*, '(''['', A, '']'')') C

      STOP
      END
```

This outputs the 52 characters,

```
[The quick brown fox ...                           ]
```

I want instead for it to output whatever the `READ` statement put into the `C` array and not all the extra space in the `C` buffer.

In the above case I'd like the output to be `[The quick brown fox ...]` or in the case where `(A5)` is used as the format instead of `(A)` for the `READ` statement, then I'd like the output to be `[The q]`

I'd like to see the result for any arbitrary format used int the `READ` statement

How can I do this?

*UPDATE*

Since it seems that this is not possible directly, is it possible to pre-populate the character variable with some esoteric character (i.e. `~`) and then overwrite with the `READ` statement?

My attempts so far seem to be overwritten by the Fortran `READ` statement i.e.

```
      PROGRAM FOO

      CHARACTER(LEN=50) :: INP
      CHARACTER(LEN=50) :: C

      C = REPEAT('~', 50)
      INP = 'The quick brown fox ...'

      READ (INP, '(TR50, A1)') C
      WRITE (*, '(''['', A, '']'')') C

      STOP
      END

! Outputs [<50 blanks>] rather than [<50 tildas>] or [ <49 tildas>]
! which would tell me if Fortran always reads a number of characters 
! equal to the specified width or never reads any characters beyond
! the end of the record

! n.b. I am interested in actual output for individual platforms, 
! not what the spec says
```

Answer (score 4):

Normal Fortran strings are fixed length and filled on the end with blanks.   So you can't tell how long the input was by examining the string later, or tell whether trailing blanks were read, or filled in to extend the string.   This is fairly fundamental.  It is a different strategy from some other languages, such as using a terminator character.   Perhaps it is primitive, but on the other hand buffer overflows are impossible.

There are now two ways to have variable length strings in Fortran.   For some years there has been an ISO standard for a module ISO_VARYING_STRING.   There are open source implementations of this module.   You "call GET" to read a string and "call PUT_LINE" to write it.   While this module has not been popular, I found it to work well.

The more recent alternative (a feature of Fortran 2003) is allocatable scalers.  I am less familar with the use of this for variable-length strings, and until recently it was supported by few compilers.   From the web, the syntax for the declaration is:

```
CHARACTER(LEN=:), ALLOCATABLE :: S
```

Comment: Ah, is [this module](ftp://ftp.liv.ac.uk/pub/fortran_std/is1539-2.html#MOD) the one you are referring to?

Comment: ISO/IEC 1539-2 is the document / specification.  Here is an implementation: http://www.fortran.com/iso_varying_string.f95

Comment: There does not seem to be a way to use these string with `READ` statements, only its own `GET` statement - the purpose of my code is to test how the `READ` statement behaves with various formats on various platforms ...

Answer (score 1):

If you need to eliminate blank space at the end of the string, you can use the `trim` function:

```
program foo

    character(len=24) :: inp
    character(len=50) :: c

    inp = 'The quick brown fox ...'
    read (inp, '(A5)') c
    write (*, '(''['',A,'']'')') trim(c)
    read (inp, '(A)') c
    write (*, '(''['',A,'']'')') trim(c)
end program foo
```

prints

```
[The q]
[The quick brown fox ...]
```

**Edit**: As noted in the comment, if you want to truncate the string for as many characters as were read, and you *know* how long it is (e.g. you typed in A5 for the format string) you can just select the substring:

```
read(inp, '(A5)') c
write (*, '(''['',A,'']'')') c(1:5)
```

works for the case of A4 where you want the space printed.  If you want the length to vary, you can store the format string.  In the case of length 4, this would be like

```
character(len=10) :: fmt
fmt = '(A4)'
read(inp, fmt) c
```

You could then construct `fmt` using an integer variable and use that same integer variable as the index in the string slice.

Comment: Ah, unfortunately some of the strings that are read in may end in a space i.e. if `(A4)` is used in the `READ` statement, I would expect `[The ]` to be returned, not `[The]` ...

Comment: Thanks for the extra input, however in the example, the width is not specified with the bare `A` edit descriptor. Also in more complicated cases - for example where the format is `(TR5, A4)` - the widths of the read string is not simply the width of the `A` descriptor. I am trying to remain as agnostic to the format used as possible since I am automatically generating large anounts Fortran tests (using Python) which input all sorts of unusual Format statements to determine the behaviour of the Read statement on various Fortran platforms

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem: I have to read lines from a file which have sometimes trailing blanks that i need to preserve in order to keep the program running, which needs those blanks somehow.

found out that the use of the ISO_VARYING_STRING extension works but in speed it has no advantage to my simple and very inefficient looking solution:

```
subroutine stringread(rcache,l)
implicit none
integer :: i,l, ierr
character(80) :: rcache
l=0
do i=1,81
    read(20,'(A1)',advance='NO',iostat=ierr) rcache(i:i)
    if (ierr.ne.0) exit
    l=i
end do
write(30, '(A)') rcache(1:l)
end subroutine stringread
```

simply reading the lines of a file char by char into a string until an error (end of line) occurs. meanwhile the chars read are counted in l, so i can output with rcache(1:l) exactly what i read.

the solution may look very ugly but surprisingly gives no speed disadvantage for big files compared to the elegant solution with ISO_VARYING_STRING.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution to preserve an intended trailing blank would be to concatenate your string with a the nul character:

```
  PROGRAM FOO

  CHARACTER(LEN=25) :: INP
  CHARACTER(LEN=50) :: C

  INP = 'The quick brown fox ...'//CHAR(0)

  READ (INP, '(A)') C

  I=1
  DO
    IF (I.EQ.LEN(C).OR.C(I:I).EQ.CHAR(0)) EXIT
    I=I+1
  ENDDO
  WRITE (*, '(''['', A, '']'')') C(1:I)

  STOP
  END
```

Comment: Interesting, sort of like emulating C strings. Unfortunately if the edit descriptor was `A4` for example, then the null character would not be at the end.

Comment: well, you know the length of the string is the minimum of `I` and the size of the input format, so in that case for `A4` it would be `MIN(4,I)`